# expected value of two LTI output signals multiplied (cross correlation)

Tags: linear-systems, random-process, stochastic

I have an input signal x (assumed to be iid Gaussian with $\mu=0$, $\sigma^2$) which is fed into two linear systems:

- $y_1 = h_1 * x$
- $y_2 = h_2 * x$

Now I would like to calculate $\mathbb{E}[y_1 y_2]$. What is the proper way to do this - preferably in the **frequency domain**?

Background: I want to calculate something like $\operatorname{var}(y_1 + y_2)$. This expands to $\operatorname{var}(y_1)+\operatorname{var}(y_2)+2\mathbb{E}[y_1 y_2]$. Now I am very familar with the first two components - the variance. I know that the variance of a stochastic signal is given by the autocorrelation sequence at position 0. With the Wiener-Kinchin theorem this translates to:

$$
\operatorname{var}(y_1) = r_{yy}(0) = \int_0^{\infty} \Phi_{yy}(f) df
$$

and then:

$$
\cdots = \sigma_x^2 \int_0^{\infty} |H_1(f)|^2 df
$$

Now for my problem - with $\mathbb{E}[y_1 y_2]$ I arrive at $\mathbb{E}[x^2 \cdots]$ (giving a variance) but the filter is not square magnitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assumimg that the two linear systems are BIBO-stable*, the random processes $\{Y_1(t)\}$ and $\{Y_2(t)\}$ are zero-mean WSS Gaussian processes with autocorrelation functions and power spectral densities given by 
\begin{align}
R_{Y_1} &= \sigma^2 (h_1 \star \tilde{h}_1)\\
R_{Y_2} &= \sigma^2 (h_2 \star \tilde{h}_2)\\
S_{Y_1} &= \sigma^2 |H_1|^2\\
S_{Y_2} &= \sigma^2 |H_2|^2
\end{align}
In fact, the processes are also *jointly* Gaussian and *jointly WSS* processes with *cross-correlation* function $$R_{Y_1, Y_2}(\tau) = E[Y_1(t), Y_2(t+\tau)] = \sigma^2 (h_1 \star \tilde{h}_2)$$ and *cross-power spectral density* 
$$S_{Y_1,Y_2}(f) = \sigma^2 H_1(f)H_2^*(f).$$
The OP wants to find $E[Y_1(t)Y_2(t)]$ which is given by
\begin{align}E[Y_1(t)Y_2(t)] &= R_{Y_1,Y_2}(0)\\
&= \sigma^2 h_1\star \tilde{h}_2\big|_{\tau=0}\tag{1}\\
&= \sigma^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_1(f)H_2^*(f) \,\mathrm df\tag{2}
\end{align}
since the OP prefers the frequency-domain calculation. Personally, given only $h_1$ and $h_2$ (and not $H_1$ and $H_2$), I would say that it is easier/cheaper to just grind out $(1)$ rather than use the frequency-domain calculation $(2)$ but the OP might have specific reasons for opting for the frequency-domain calculation. In particular, $\operatorname{var}(Y_1+Y_2)$ which is what the OP seems to really want to find is just
$$\operatorname{var}(Y_1+Y_2) = \sigma^2\begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty |h_1(t)+h_2(t)|^2 \,\mathrm dt,\\
\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |h_1[n]+h_2[n]|^2\end{cases}$$
which seems easier than the frequency-domain version of the same calculation, but ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the convolution operator as a [matrix operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution) by building a Toeplitz matrix for the impulse response function. Your equations can be rewritten as $Y_1 = H_1 X$ and $Y_2 = H_2 X$, where $Y_1 = [y^1_1,\ldots,y^n_1]^T$,   $Y_2 = [y^1_2,\ldots,y^n_2]^T$, $X = [x_1,\ldots,x_m]^T$, $m$ is the length of the input vector, and $n$ is the length of the convolution product which depends on length of the input vector and the length of the impulse response function.

Now, $Y_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 H_1 H_1^T)$, $Y_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 H_2 H_2^T)$, and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 I)$.

Therefore,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y_1 Y_2^T) &= \mathbb{E}(H_1 X X^T H_2^T) \\
&= H_1 \mathbb{E}(X X^T) H_2^T \\
&= \sigma^2 H_1 H_2^T
\end{align}

Comment: I was thinking about an approach such as that but couldn't figure out how to get $H$. Now I know. Thanks.